# Mentioning Data type of list elements twice in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to Dart and Flutter, and I'm following a basic flutter [tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/first-flutter-app-pt1/#5), referred to from the [official fultter docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/codelab).

At the [6th step](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/first-flutter-app-pt1/#5) in the tutorial, I came across this line of code:

```
final List<WordPair> _suggestions = <WordPair>[];
```

However, even if I changed the line to

```
final List<WordPair> _suggestions = [];
```

the code produced the same result. Note that this list stores some objects whose contents are displayed in the application.

Are both the cases same ? If yes, which one makes more sense semantically and should be preferred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They both do the same thing - instantiate the list. If you don't add the 
`<WordPair>` beforehand, dart just assumes that the type is the same as the one on the left side. Either way is correct.